# On screen video recording software for Linux

Tags: linux, open-source, ubuntu, screen-recording, video-recording

I am looking for Video recording software for Ubuntu 16.04lts that has:

1. Able to pause the recording and continue it on some other DAY
2. Able to fast forward my 120 hrs recording into 2mins file recordings

Note: Audio is not required, just the video recording is sufficient.

Comment: https://hackerspace.kinja.com/screen-recording-in-linux-1686055808 You might find these to your use.

Comment: your tasks may be better done afterwards with a video editing software...

Comment: @harishaaram Were you able to find the answer to this ?

Comment: @TedTaylorofLife No! I am not able find it.

Comment: Electron has a desktop capture API that I think works for Linux if you don’t mind writing a bit of code. Here is some example usage: https://github.com/styfle/magnemite